# Samsung Tizen -

Tags: tizen, tizen-emulator

When i try to start the emulator manager i get the following error:
"Emulator manager is not installed" as shown here:

[image]

So i went to the path for my sdk and it looks like this:

[image]

How can i get a emulator ? I am using Mac OS

and when i go into tools folder theres no binary there:

[image]

Comment: Have you asked Google first?

Comment: Clearly. Samsung makes it difficult to find. They should just do step a-z instead

Comment: Seems like on Linux ( at least Ubuntu ) you'll need `qemu-kvm` for the emulator to work. Not pretty sure on OS X

Answer (score 1):

I was using the installer located here on there developer site:

[image]

doing it this way, you need to launch the update manager to get additional components you need.  The update manager can be found here:

[image]

The emulator is included here for whatever sdk you need.